# Provider in Android Manifest

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I've created an SQLite Location Content Provider. I've placed it in my manifest. Only problem is that I don't want the tables to form until I open a certain activity within my app. Currently the LocationContentProvider builds the tables automatically when the app is open. I don't want that to happen because certain items like the table name aren't determined until a certain activity in my app.

Why does the provider start automatically when I open the app? How do I get it to not start until say a button click within a certain activity?

Here is my LocationContentProvider:

```
public class LocationsContentProvider extends ContentProvider{

public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "com.blah.blah.blah";

/** A uri to do operations on locations table. A content provider is identified by its uri */
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + PROVIDER_NAME + "/locations" );

/** Constant to identify the requested operation */
private static final int LOCATIONS = 1; 

private static final UriMatcher uriMatcher ;

static {
    uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    uriMatcher.addURI(PROVIDER_NAME, "locations", LOCATIONS);       
}

/** This content provider does the database operations by this object */
LocationsDB mLocationsDB;

/** A callback method which is invoked when the content provider is starting up */
@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mLocationsDB = new LocationsDB(getContext());
    return true;
}

/** A callback method which is invoked when insert operation is requested on this content provider */
@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    long rowID = mLocationsDB.insert(values);
    Uri _uri=null;
    if(rowID>0){
        _uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, rowID);
    }else {     
        try {
            throw new SQLException("Failed to insert : " + uri);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return _uri;    
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



/** A callback method which is invoked when delete operation is requested on this content provider */
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int cnt = 0;        
    cnt = mLocationsDB.del();   
    return cnt;
}

/** A callback method which is invoked by default content uri */
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) { 

    if(uriMatcher.match(uri)==LOCATIONS){
        return mLocationsDB.getAllLocations();
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {        
    return null;
}   
}
```

Here is my database helper:

```
public class LocationsDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

/** Database name */
private static String DBNAME = "locationmarkersqlite";

/** Version number of the database */
private static int VERSION = 1;

/** Field 1 of the table locations, which is the primary key */
public static final String FIELD_ROW_ID = "_id";

/** Field 2 of the table locations, stores the latitude */
public static final String FIELD_LAT = "lat";

/** Field 3 of the table locations, stores the longitude*/
public static final String FIELD_LNG = "lng";

public static final String FIELD_BEAR = "bear";

public static final String FIELD_BOOMWIDTH = "boomwidth";

public static final String FIELD_COMMENTS = "comments";


/** Field 4 of the table locations, stores the zoom level of map*/
public static final String FIELD_ZOOM = "zom";

/** A constant, stores the the table name */
static String tablename = PolygonEngine.DATABASE_TABLE;

public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "tablename";

/** An instance variable for SQLiteDatabase */
private SQLiteDatabase mDB;  


/** Constructor */
public LocationsDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, VERSION);  
    this.mDB = getWritableDatabase();
}


/** This is a callback method, invoked when the method getReadableDatabase() / getWritableDatabase() is called 
  * provided the database does not exists 
* */
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql =    "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( " +
                        FIELD_ROW_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement , " +
                        FIELD_LNG + " double , " +
                        FIELD_LAT + " double , " +
                        FIELD_BEAR + " double , " +
                        FIELD_BOOMWIDTH + " double , " +
                        FIELD_COMMENTS + " text , " +
                        FIELD_ZOOM + " text " +
                    " ) ";

    db.execSQL(sql);
}

/** Inserts a new location to the table locations */
public long insert(ContentValues contentValues){
    long rowID = mDB.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    return rowID;

}   


/** Deletes all locations from the table */
public int del(){
    int cnt = mDB.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null , null);      
    return cnt;
}

/** Returns all the locations from the table */
public Cursor getAllLocations(){
    return mDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { FIELD_ROW_ID,  FIELD_LAT , FIELD_LNG, FIELD_BEAR, FIELD_BOOMWIDTH, FIELD_COMMENTS, FIELD_ZOOM } , null, null, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

}
```

Comment: I don't have this problem with my content provider starting by itself?  However it does start when the app requests something from it.

Comment: I have no references to the provider whatsoever within my starting activity.

Comment: And there's nothing in your code doing a contentresolver().query ?  Because that's where my custom provider first starts.